# How do I add a pre-compiled shared library with existing NDK project?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I had a project working fine with the normal gradle using two separate shared libraries. I was including the libraries with the following gradle commands:

```
    sourceSets.main
        {
            jni.srcDirs = []// This means that ndk-build.cmd needs to be invoked from command line
            jniLibs.srcDirs "src/main/libs" //include other libraries
        }
```

I needed to begin compiling one of the two libraries, so I moved to experimental gradle. I got this to work fine for the library that I am building. But, when I go to add the pre-compiled shared library, I am getting a crash for java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for my JNI method. I have not changed the package name or the shared library.

When I run

```
jar xvf app-release.apk
```

I see my shared library present in the list of files, so it is being picked up by the APK build. What could be the source of the UnsatisfiedLinkError if the library is in the APK? What are the steps to include a prebuilt .so file into an NDK project. The NDK project code does not call into the extra library, only the java code.

Answer (score 0):

You should load your library manually from java code.

```
System.loadLibrary("yourlib");
```

Don't forget to handle exceptions, as `loadLibrary` can throw one. It's important, because exception message would show you the paths, where it tried to find your shared library. Also be sure, your library was added to your **apk**. Then, be sure you have your shared library compiled for different ABI, as armeabi library won't work on x86 phone.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ph0b/418132cb2f3f03a5534c) you can find an example of adding library to your project with gradle-experimental plugin, so it would be added to your **apk**.